# Charset not present in used JDK

Tags: java, character-encoding, mainframe, charset

I have a java system communicating that serves as a gateway to different systems (java, mainframe, etc). This java system receives a request using, for example, utf8 and converts it to the encoding of the target

[image: Charset Conversion]

The issue is that there is a mainframe system that is using this obscure encoding that is not available with the JDK that we are using (that charset being IBM-924 which is a "derivative" of IBM-1047 https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Character_Encodings/Code_Tables/EBCDIC/EBCDIC_1047).
system.

From what I have seen this charset seems to come only with IBM JDK, which is not the one that we use or want to use.

Is there a way to incorporate this specific charset present on the IBM JDK into, for example, an openjdk one?
If not, is there any alternative beside creating the charset manually?
And if so, is there a way to reuse the IBM-1047 encoding and replace the 11 characters that do not match?

I tried to incorporate the charsets by using the charsets.jar present on the IBM JDK, but it runs into issues because that jar has a dependency of classes only present on the rt.jar of the IBM JDK, and I would certainly not want to replace the rt.jar since it might cause unwanted side effects.

Comment: [`IBM1047`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/intl/supported-encodings.html) is bundled, at least with every OpenJDK-based implementation. Perhaps you could use the [OpenJDK source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk) as a guide to write your own implementation of an IBM 924 [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).  You may need to implement a `CharsetProvider` as well, to leverage the [Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) facility, as noted in the Javadoc.

Comment: FYI… I tried adding more `CharSet` classes from the [*ICU4J Charset Provider*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j-charset) of the [ICU4J](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/) project adapting [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) for Java. This did add 111 more `Charset` objects to the 173 found in Java 20, for a total of 284. Unfortunately, none of these were your elusive IBM 924. (Calling `Charset.availableCharsets` lists all available `Charset` objects.)

Comment: Can you provide a link for the "IBM JDK" you mentioned?

Comment: Indeed the amount of time it took me to figure out it was 924... let's just say, I have a new hatred for IBM... I wish there was a search functionality to match find charset based on combination of unicode and hexadecimal value.
Well, I didn't download a JDK per se, if you download the zip Installation Manager of IBM (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/installation-manager-and-packaging-utility-download-documents) there is a JRE there and on the lib/charsets.jar you'll find the 924 charset.

Comment: By the way, ICU4J seems to include a [*Character Set Detection*](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/conversion/detection.html#character-set-detection) feature. I don't know if this would have helped you though, since ICU4J seems to be unaware of IBM 924 per my Comment above.

Comment: ICU4J does offer an [encoding conversion](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/conversion/) feature. I don't know if this is helpful to you or not.

Comment: FYI, I tried IBM’s [Semeru](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/) JDK version 20.0.2 to list available `Charset` objects. I got a total of 173, just like I did with Azul System’s Zulu 20.0.2 JDK, so I assume they are the same set of `Charset` objects. Certainly no "924" among them.

Comment: Did you try to download the installation manager of IBM, it contains a JRE folder, if you unzip the charsets.jar and go into sun.nio.cs.ext you'll find the elusive 924.
You have the list of charsets also on the ExtendedCharsets.class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oof, IBM_924 almost doesn't exist on the entire internet. Looking around, it seems to either be [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) straight up (which *is* something JDKs ship with, so just go with `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15")`, or..

It's [this](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu-data/blob/main/charset/data/ucm/ibm-924_P100-1998.ucm), from [*ICU Data*](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu_data/#icu-data) by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium).

That is some random mapping file I found from some random project (admittedly, the icu-data project from the unicode organisation; as far as sources go that one should be sufficiently authoritative). You read it as follows:

A line might contain:

```
<UFF5E> \xA1 |1
```

And this means:

- If you see the byte `0xA1` in the data stream...
- Then that represents character 0xFF5E in the unicode table.
- That `|1` means, more or less: Not roundtrippable; it's an alias. There is a more canonical mapping for the same byte (`0xA1`) in the file earlier.

And, fortunately, being an ISO-8559 variant, it's just '1 byte = 1 character', therefore, there are only at most 256 different byte values you need to map to a character.

**That means it is trivial to write your own charset implementation!**

And thus you've solved all problems: House the charset inside your own project, and now you have no dependencies and no need to rely on a JVM that ships with IBM-924 baked in.

It's not too difficult.

Make a source file named `Ibm924CharsetProvider.java`, extending from Java’s [`CharsetProvider`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/valhalla/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html) class. Copy/paste this into it:

```java
// Written by Reinier Zwitserloot
// Public domain - use however you like.

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.CoderResult;
import java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Ibm924CharsetProvider extends CharsetProvider {
    private static final Charset IBM924 = new Ibm924Charset();
    private static final List<Charset> IBM924_LIST = Collections.singletonList(IBM924);
    
    public static final Charset ibm924() {
        return IBM924;
    }
    
    @Override public Iterator<Charset> charsets() {
        return IBM924_LIST.iterator();
    }
    
    @Override public Charset charsetForName(String charsetName) {
        if (charsetName.equals(IBM924.name())) return IBM924;
        if (IBM924.aliases().contains(charsetName)) return IBM924;
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String in = "Hello, World!";
        byte[] b = in.getBytes(ibm924());
        System.out.print(in + " ->");
        for (byte a : b) System.out.printf(" %02X", a);
        System.out.println();
        String in2 = new String(b, ibm924());
        System.out.println("... -> " + in2);
        System.out.println("Equal? " + in.equals(in2));
    }
}

class Ibm924Charset extends Charset {
    public Ibm924Charset() {
        super("IBM-924", new String[] { "IBM924", "Cp924", "Cp-924" });
    }
    
    @Override public boolean contains(Charset cs) {
        return cs.name().equals("IBM-924"); // It isn't even a subset of ASCII!
    }
    
    @Override public CharsetDecoder newDecoder() {
        return new CharsetDecoder(this, 1F, 1F) {
            @Override protected CoderResult decodeLoop(ByteBuffer from, CharBuffer to) {
                while (from.hasRemaining()) {
                    if (!to.hasRemaining()) return CoderResult.OVERFLOW;
                    byte c = from.get();
                    char d = IBM924[c & 0xFF];
                    to.put(d);
                }
                
                return CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Override public CharsetEncoder newEncoder() {
        return new CharsetEncoder(this, 1F, 1F) {
            @Override protected CoderResult encodeLoop(CharBuffer from, ByteBuffer to) {
                while (from.hasRemaining()) {
                    if (!to.hasRemaining()) return CoderResult.OVERFLOW;
                    char d = from.get();
                    Byte v = LOOKUP.get(d);
                    if (v == null) {
                        // 'un'consume the character we consumed
                        from.position(from.position() - 1);
                        return CoderResult.unmappableForLength(1);
                    }
                    to.put(v.byteValue());
                }
                
                return CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
            }
        };
    }
    
    // SOURCE: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu-data/blob/main/charset/data/ucm/ibm-924_P100-1998.ucm
    private static final char[] IBM924 = {
        '\u0000', '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u009C', '\u0009', '\u0086', '\u007F',
        '\u0097', '\u008D', '\u008E', '\u000B', '\u000C', '\r', '\u000E', '\u000F',
        '\u0010','\u0011','\u0012','\u0013', '\u009D','\u0085','\u0008','\u0087',
        '\u0018','\u0019','\u0092','\u008F', '\u001C','\u001D','\u001E','\u001F',
        '\u0080','\u0081','\u0082','\u0083', '\u0084','\n','\u0017','\u001B',
        '\u0088','\u0089','\u008A','\u008B', '\u008C','\u0005', '\u0006', '\u0007',
        '\u0090', '\u0091', '\u0016', '\u0093', '\u0094', '\u0095', '\u0096', '\u0004',
        '\u0098', '\u0099', '\u009A', '\u009B', '\u0014', '\u0015', '\u009E', '\u001A',
        '\u0020', '\u00A0', '\u00E2', '\u00E4', '\u00E0', '\u00E1', '\u00E3', '\u00E5',
        '\u00E7', '\u00F1', '\u00DD', '\u002E', '\u003C', '\u0028', '\u002B', '\u007C',
        '\u0026', '\u00E9', '\u00EA', '\u00EB', '\u00E8', '\u00ED', '\u00EE', '\u00EF',
        '\u00EC', '\u00DF', '\u0021', '\u0024', '\u002A', '\u0029', '\u003B', '\u005E',
        '\u002D', '\u002F', '\u00C2', '\u00C4', '\u00C0', '\u00C1', '\u00C3', '\u00C5',
        '\u00C7', '\u00D1', '\u0160', '\u002C', '\u0025', '\u005F', '\u003E', '\u003F',
        '\u00F8', '\u00C9', '\u00CA', '\u00CB', '\u00C8', '\u00CD', '\u00CE', '\u00CF',
        '\u00CC', '\u0060', '\u003A', '\u0023', '\u0040', '\'', '\u003D', '\u0022',
        '\u00D8', '\u0061', '\u0062', '\u0063', '\u0064', '\u0065', '\u0066', '\u0067',
        '\u0068', '\u0069', '\u00AB', '\u00BB', '\u00F0', '\u00FD', '\u00FE', '\u00B1',
        '\u00B0', '\u006A', '\u006B', '\u006C', '\u006D', '\u006E', '\u006F', '\u0070',
        '\u0071', '\u0072', '\u00AA', '\u00BA', '\u00E6', '\u017E', '\u00C6', '\u20AC',
        '\u00B5', '\u007E', '\u0073', '\u0074', '\u0075', '\u0076', '\u0077', '\u0078',
        '\u0079', '\u007A', '\u00A1', '\u00BF', '\u00D0', '\u005B', '\u00DE', '\u00AE',
        '\u00A2', '\u00A3', '\u00A5', '\u00B7', '\u00A9', '\u00A7', '\u00B6', '\u0152',
        '\u0153', '\u0178', '\u00AC', '\u0161', '\u00AF', '\u005D', '\u017D', '\u00D7',
        '\u007B', '\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u0044', '\u0045', '\u0046', '\u0047',
        '\u0048', '\u0049', '\u00AD', '\u00F4', '\u00F6', '\u00F2', '\u00F3', '\u00F5',
        '\u007D', '\u004A', '\u004B', '\u004C', '\u004D', '\u004E', '\u004F', '\u0050',
        '\u0051', '\u0052', '\u00B9', '\u00FB', '\u00FC', '\u00F9', '\u00FA', '\u00FF',
        '\\', '\u00F7', '\u0053', '\u0054', '\u0055', '\u0056', '\u0057', '\u0058',
        '\u0059', '\u005A', '\u00B2', '\u00D4', '\u00D6', '\u00D2', '\u00D3', '\u00D5',
        '\u0030', '\u0031', '\u0032', '\u0033', '\u0034', '\u0035', '\u0036', '\u0037',
        '\u0038', '\u0039', '\u00B3', '\u00DB', '\u00DC', '\u00D9', '\u00DA', '\u009F',
    };
    
    private static final Map<Character, Byte> LOOKUP;
    static {
        Map<Character, Byte> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < IBM924.length; i++) map.put(IBM924[i], (byte) i);
        LOOKUP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

### To use as provider

If you want e.g. `new String(bytes, "IBM-924")` to work, as well as having it listed in the list of all available charsets, this class needs to be registered. To do this, you stick the fully qualified class name (`com.foo.yourapp.util.Ibm924CharsetProvider`, that string, for example) in an otherwise empty text file. You name this textfile `java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider`. This file needs to be in your jar, at the path `META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider`. Then, if that jar is on your classpath, things should just work.

### Oof that sounds complicated

You don't really need to do that - that's just to make sure `"IBM-924"` as a string works out. You can use it as is without registering the provider. See the `main` method in the snippet where I don't bother registering it but use the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) object directly.

Run that, and it prints:

```
Hello, World! -> C8 85 93 93 96 6B 40 E6 96 99 93 84 5A
... -> Hello, World!
Equal? true
```

NB: This simplistic take doesn't deal with the aliases. They are only relevant for *encoding* (if you need to output IBM-924 formatted text); they aren't useful for decoding (reading IBM-924 formatted text). And only if you use these aliases in your strings.

Comment: Indeed the decoding is working with the correct hexadecimal values. Thanks for that! However, I'm having trouble getting the CharsetProvider to work. I created a jar with the following structure:  
my/package/Ibm924CharsetProvider.class
META-INF/services/java.nio.charsets.spi.CharsetProvider (which inside has my.package.Ibm924CharsetProvider)
I then added the jar to the lib/ext folder of my jre.
However when trying to execute:
byte[] b = in.getBytes("IBM-924");
In a very simple main it gives Exception in thread "main" java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: IBM-924
Am I missing something?

Comment: *I then added the jar to the lib/ext folder of my jre* That's history >= Java 9

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph, ISO-8859-15, does not have the same hexadecimal value for the same unicode value, so you will get a different characters from what you would expect if the charset used was IBM-924 and you tried to decode in ISO-8859-15, e.g., if you tried to decode de symbol "€" from ISO-8859-15 to IBM-924, you would get a "u" instead of "€" since in ISO-8859-15 the hex value is 0xA4 but on IBM-924 it is 0x9F

Comment: @g00se I'm using java 8, but anyway, I tried adding the jar directly in the classpath, it still didn't work, i.e., java -cp Charset924.jar;. MyTest

Comment: Maybe the provider setup is wrong. I don't do those, so can't help unfortunately. Fun fact: `iconv` lists 287 IBM conversions on my machine. IBM924 isn't one of them ;)

Comment: I've got one working if you want it

Comment: If you could share it, that would be great!

Comment: You're on Windows are you?

Comment: Yes, I'm running locally on windows but the servers on other environments are running in Linux, so either one will serve.

Comment: Just checking - as your classpath was a Windows one ;) [Here you go](https://technojeeves.com/tech/ibm924.jar)

Comment: 3 freaking hours looking for the problem, it was just a typo on the services file, had java.nio.charsets.spi.CharsetProvider instead of java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider, thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: I often do that. Fortunately it's when something needs to be compiled